# How to select an object from an array where a certain property is minimal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I'm just getting my head around Coffescript and have come across a requirement to select an object from an array where a particular property is minimal. I've set out my basic code below:

```
class Point
    constructor: (@x, @y, @z) ->

    addedTogether: ->
        @x+@y+@z

class PointCollection
    constructor: ->
        @points = []

    add: (point) ->
        @points.push(point)

    minimalPoint: ->
        // need to return point with lowest addedTogether value

samplePoints = new PointCollection()
samplePoints.add(new Point(1,2,3))
samplePoints.add(new Point(2,3,4))
samplePoints.add(new Point(3,4,5))
samplePoints.add(new Point(4,5,6))
samplePoints.add(new Point(5,6,7))
samplePoints.add(new Point(1,1,1))

lowestValuePoint = samplePoints.minimalPoint()
```

I can obviously do that in plain old javascript with a function like:

```
function findPointWithLowestScore(points) {
    var lowestScoringPoint = points[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

    lowestScoringPoint = (points[i].addedTogether() < lowestScoringPoint.addedTogether()) ? points[i] :    lowestScoringPoint;
    }
    return lowestScoringPoint;
}
```

but is there a nicer, cleaner, CoffeeScript-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class Point
    constructor: (@x, @y, @z) ->

    addedTogether: ->
        @x+@y+@z

class PointCollection
    constructor: ->
        @points = []

    add: (point) ->
        @points.push(point)

    minimalPoint: ->
        tmp = @points.slice 0 # duplicate array
        tmp.sort (a, b) -> a.addedTogether() - b.addedTogether() # Sort from lowest to highest
        tmp[0] # Return the first element

samplePoints = new PointCollection()
samplePoints.add(new Point(1,2,3))
samplePoints.add(new Point(2,3,4))
samplePoints.add(new Point(3,4,5))
samplePoints.add(new Point(4,5,6))
samplePoints.add(new Point(5,6,7))
samplePoints.add(new Point(1,1,1))

lowestValuePoint = samplePoints.minimalPoint()
```

Comment: This worked great thanks, the line tmp= @points.slice 0 can be replaced with tmp = @points[..] that's shorthand for the same thing but I think reads better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class PointCollection
    # ...
    compare: (p1, p2) -> p1.addedTogether() - p2.addedTogether()

    minimalPoint: ->
        minPoint = points[0]
        minVal = if compare(minPoint, point) > 0 then point else minPoint for point in points
```